# How to get the primary group of a user?

Tags: linux, group

The following command will list all of the groups of `someUser` (the primary group and the supplementary groups):

```
groups someUser
```

But is there a way to only get the primary group?

Comment: Isn't the primary group listed first?

Comment: @simlev I reached here looking for info on that. On my recent arch linux install that doesn't seem to be the case. It shows "wheel" as the first group. But doing id -gn shows the primary group that I would expect.

Comment: @reportaman I cannot confirm this: I just installed a new arch, ran `useradd myuser; usermod -aG wheel myuser` and got `gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),998(wheel)`.

Answer (score 44):

See the FreeBSD [handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-synopsis.html) (information also valid for Linux):

> **Group ID (GID)**
>
> The Group ID (GID) is a number used to uniquely identify the primary group that the user belongs to. Groups are a mechanism for
>   controlling access to resources based on a user's GID rather than
>   their UID. This can significantly reduce the size of some
>   configuration files and allows users to be members of more than one
>   group. It is recommended to use a GID of 65535 or lower as higher GIDs
>   may break some software.

If so, running `id <username>` will show `gid=<primary group>`:

```
id <username>
uid=1000(<username>) gid=1000(<username>) groups=1000(<username>),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo)
```

If you want the command to return just the primary group name, see `man id`:

> ```
>    -g, --group
>           print only the effective group ID
>
>    -G, --groups
>           print all group IDs
>
>    -n, --name
>           print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
> ```

so, `id -gn <username>` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since `groups <username>` will list the primary group of the user first, you can use the following to only extract the primary group of the specified user:

`groups <username> | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: On Archlinux 2023-7-23, this is not true. The output of `groups` is sorted alphabetically.